# Issues with finding a gateway with static routing

Tags: network, linux

I am doing this online lab where I am hosting a Kali Linux box in VmWare fusion, and VPNing into the online lab. These are my networking adapters once I connect via VPN:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.44  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fead:540a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:ad:54:0a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1578  bytes 1605108 (1.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 517  bytes 52627 (51.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 40  bytes 1972 (1.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 40  bytes 1972 (1.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.193.73  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.193.255
        inet6 fe80::1c6b:dff:feac:a0c1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1e:6b:0d:ac:a0:c1  txqueuelen 100  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 36  bytes 3960 (3.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6  bytes 516 (516.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I found a Wireshark file that revealed there are two hosts on the following networks:

```
10.86.74.7 
10.85.174.87
```

When I try to ping those IPs, packets don't go through. The lab specifically says I need to create a static route, but I don't understand exactly what this means.

What command would I need to use exactly to be able to connect to these two other networks from the network I am actually IN, which is

192.168.193.0/24

My IP on that network is 192.168.193.72....

Yes, I know this question was asked before but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: This is not a security question. This is a pure networking question.

Comment: Might I suggest that you ""Try harder"?